# Product view error in admin panel Magento 2

Tags: product, javascript, admin-panel, knockoutjs, requirejs

Not able to view the product in the admin panel.
getting below error in console.

```
Unable to process binding "if: function(){return label }"
Message: label is not defined
```

I am not finding any fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not your custom extension that it's causing that, I recommend testing disabling all third-party modules running this command below if it disappears you can enable each module until discovering which one is causing it.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"
mage module:status | grep -v Magento | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable
rm -rf  vendor/magento var/composer_home/cache
composer update -vvvv
mage setup:upgrade
mage cache:flush
mage indexer:reindex
mage deploy:mode:set developer
setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

If you are creating a custom module you need to add a `ko.observable()`, like in the example below.

```
self.label = ko.observable(null);
```

Comment: Where i need to add this code?

Comment: @jafarpinjar I changed my answer

Comment: okay let me try this